# document.getElementById("spanid").innerHTML is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript, so I can't really find what's wrong in my code.
Below is the code:

```
<script language="javascript">

var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter the first number.",""));
var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter the second number.",""));
var z = prompt("Enter an operation.","");
var total = 0;

switch (z) {
  case "1":
  case "+":
  case "add":
  case "addition":
  case "sum":
    var total = x + y;
    break;
  case "2":
  case "-":
  case "sub":
  case "subtract":
  case "subtraction":
  case "diff":
  case "difference":
    var total = x - y;
    break;
  case "3":
  case "x":
  case "*":
  case "mult":
  case "multiply":
  case "multiplication":
  case "prod":
  case "product":
    var total = x * y;
    break;
  case "4":
  case "/":
  case "divide":
  case "division":
  case "quo":
  case "quotient":
    if (y == 0) {
      document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = "Error. You cannot divide by 0."
  } else {
    var total = x / y;
  } break;
  default:
    document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = "There is something wrong with one of your inputs. Please reload the page."
}

if (isNaN(total) == false) {
  document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = total
}
```

When I input 0 to the prompt for variable y, it doesn't show "Error. You cannot divide by 0." and instead shows just 0. There is totally a span with the id of total1.

The span id was formerly "total" so I changed it to "total1" but it still did not work..

Comment: Show current HTML and JS code

Comment: What's the value of `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: You don't need `var` to assign a value to a variable. That's only for declaration (and you really should not use `var` any longer. Use `const` and `let` instead). The `language` attribute of the `<script>` element is obsolete. Either use `type="text/javascript"` with HTML4.x or just `<script>` with HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but your `span`'s innerHTML gets replaced by this block:

```
if (isNaN(total) == false) {
  document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML = total
}
```

As `total` is initialized to 0 (and doesn't change for operations like "divide") `isNaN(total)` results `false` and that writes `total` (which in this case remains `0`) in your `span` element.

Besides removing the `var` keyword (as suggested in JuanDeLasNieves's answer) you should also initialize `total` as `undefined` instead of 0:

```
var total = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare `var total = 0` in the fourth line of your code, and then in each of your cases inside the `switch` statement you re-declare it. But those variables exist just in the scope of that statement.

So, when your code reaches the final `if`, it checks if `isNan(0) == false`, which is not, so it sets the innerHTML to the value of `total`.

Solution: delete all of the `var` keywords inside the `switch` statement and try again.